# Title div that stays while scrolling but move up the next one, but stay below the nabber menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my very first stack overflow question.
I'm going nuts !!! So I need your help..

I'm building a webpage for a friend of mine but i'm stuck with section of title BAR that I what to be fix but just for certain position...

What I mean is see below...(Little Photoshop) The Color Title Bars...

I'm using Bootstrap 3, I want the titlebar to stop at 50px from top, be fixed at 50px on top, and move to the next one when it arrives...
I'm googleling anything I can, but too many fix on top (at 0px of top and not 50px), and only until the next titlebar...
Don't worry about my html or css... that is 100% ok good with me...
It's in javascript and jQuery that I'm not so good at, and I know this is a jQuery plugin or code or something...
I'm desperate here, can anyone help me out...

I have

```
<div>Hello world</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
```

[TitleBar with List to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXT7v.png)

```js
//
//
// ------- ------- ------- ------- ToolTip
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
//
//
// ------- ------- ------- ------- titlebar

//???
//???
//???

//
//
// ------- ------- ------- ------- Carousel
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
    interval: 3000
});
(function() {
    // setup your carousels as you normally would using JS
    // or via data attributes according to the documentation
    // http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
    $('#carousel123').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    });
}());
(function() {
    $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function() {
        var itemToClone = $(this);
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            itemToClone = itemToClone.next();
            // wrap around if at end of item collection
            if (!itemToClone.length) {
                itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
            itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
                .addClass("cloneditem-" + (i))
                .appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= html -->
<html lang="en">
<!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= head -->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Aliments Cibles</title>
 <link href="http://jsto.ca/test/_css/scripton.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
   .nothing {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
   }
 </style>
</head>
 <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /head -->
 <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= body -->
<body>
 <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= nav -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span><img alt="Brand" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/ac.png" height="27px"></span> Aliments Cibles
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"> 
           <a href="#">Accueil
             <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Collection
           <em>VECA™</em>
              <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
             <a href="#">
               <em>VECA™</em>&nbsp; Diabète
             </a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#"> <em>VECA™</em>&nbsp; Hypertension cardiaque
             </a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#">
               <em>VECA™</em>&nbsp; Rénal
             </a>
           </li>
           <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
           <li class="disabled">
             <a href="#"> <em>VECA™</em>&nbsp; Munitio</a>
           </li>
           <li class="disabled">
         <a href="#"> <em>VECA™
          </em>&nbsp; Performance</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li> <a href="#">Média</a> </li>
       <li class="dropdown"> 
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Info
         <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li> <a href="#">À propos</a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#">Qui sommes nous</a> </li>
         <li>
         <a href="#"> <em>VECA™</em> </a>
         </li>
         <!-- <li role="separator" class="divider"></li> -->
         <li> <a href="#">Mission</a> </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
       <li class="nothing">
         <!-- <a href="#">EN</a> -->
         <a href="#" class="nothing"> <img class="nothing" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/q.png" width="20" height="20" /> </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nothing">
         <a href="#" class="nothing"> <img class="nothing" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/c.png" width="20" height="20" />
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /nav -->
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= breadcrumb -->
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><em>VECA™</em></a></li>
   <li class="active">À quelque part dans le site</li>
  </ol>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /breadcrumb -->
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= carousel-2 -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-01.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-02.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-03.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-04.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-05.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/carousel/carousel-06.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>      -->
    <!-- -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /carousel-2 -->
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= carousel -->
  <div class="container">
   <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/car-rata.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/car-carrot.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="item"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/car-salmon.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /carousel -->
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= main -->
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1> </div>
  <div class="container-fluid titleBar-d" id="titlebar1">
   <div class="container"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/titleBar/titleBar1.png"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label1.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label2.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid titleBar-hc" id="titlebar2">
   <div class="container"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/titleBar/titleBar2.png"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label3.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label4.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid titleBar-k" id="titlebar3">
   <div class="container"> <img src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/titleBar/titleBar3.png"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label5.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://jsto.ca/test/_img/label/label6.png" /> </div>
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= Table Valeur Nutritive -->
    <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /Table Valeur Nutritive -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /main -->
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= footer -->
  <footer>
   <div class="container">
    <p>&copy; 2017 | JStO | Scripton</p>
   </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= /footer -->
  <script src="http://jsto.ca/test/_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jsto.ca/test/_js/scripton.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="http://jsto.ca/test/_js/scripton.js"></script> -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like  `position:sticky` ? but html and screenshot doesn't tell much of what you have going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expecting some reaction from my comment, here is a `position:sticky` behavior demo if your browsers runs it, else, javascript polyfill can be used.

This is more like a guess since there is no demo or code of yours showing what you have and where you get stuck.

```css
[id^=titlebar] {
  counter-increment:title ;
  background:green;
  position:sticky;
  top:1em;/* a bottom value cann be used too */
}

/* demo purpose to check wich titles stands there */
body {counter-reset:title }
[id^=titlebar]:before {
  content:counter(title)' ';
  color:yellow
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar1">Title 1</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar2">Title 2</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
<div id="titlebar3">Title 3</div>
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
```

Comment: YES !!!! That is exacly what I want, but now that I add the javascript code to my js file, nothing works anymore :-( . doesn't javascript starts with a "$" and not a "[" ???

Comment: @joelstonge this is CSS here in my demo,  not javascript. What have you done ?

Comment: Ohhhhh Slap in the face.... LOL... YES it's perfect.. thank you very much. But I had no clue this could be done in CSS, I was going trough 200 different possibilities with js and jquery and ... Thanks that awesome